# How to identify the coefficient of $x^k$ in $1/(1-x)^N$ where $N$ can be a large integer

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

I have an infinite series in the form $A(x) =\frac{1}{1-x}$ which expanded is $$A(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3...$$

I need to find the coefficient of the term $x^K$ in $A(x)^N$ where $N$ can be a large number $2^{32}$. I saw a solution over there using induction, but I didn't understand it. Please suggest a different solution or help me to understand the solution that uses induction.

Comment: Hint:  Note that $\frac {d^n}{dx^n}A(x)=\frac 1{\left(1-x\right)^n}$.

Comment: @lulu, don't you mean $\frac{1}{n!(1-x)^{n+1}}$?

Comment: Let's try to get your induction started. What's the constant term in $A(x)^2$ going to be? $1$. What about the $x$ term? $1\cdot x + x \cdot 1 = 2x$. What about $x^2$? $1\cdot x^2 + x\cdot x + x^2\cdot 1 = 3x^2$. See a pattern? Now try to figure out $A(x)^3$, and look for another pattern. Once you think you've found the general pattern, try to prove it.

Comment: If you take $A(x)=1+x+x^2\dots$ to the $N^\text{th}$ power, you are multiplying $N$ copies of it together.  By the rules of polynomial multiplication, this will be the sum of every possible product of one term from each copy.  $x^k$ terms are products of terms whose exponents total $k$, so the coefficient is the same as the number of ways to write $N$ numbers from $0$ to $k$ totaling $k$, where the order matters.  Don't know if that makes it easier or harder for you, but it's a different way of looking at it, anyway.

Comment: @KyleFerendo  Indeed I do.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You can use a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach to count the ways to add numbers up to $k$.

Comment: I think you need to find the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1-x)^{-n}$

Answer (score 2):

We can extract the coefficient of $x^k$ of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^N}$ by using the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* with $\alpha = -N$.

\begin{align*}
(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{j}x^j\qquad\qquad |x|<1, \alpha\in\mathbb{C}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ of a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^k]\frac{1}{(1-x)^N}&=[x^k](1-x)^{-N}\\
> &=[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-N}{j}(-x)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{N+j-1}{j}x^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{N+k-1}{k}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial series expansion (1) with $\alpha=-N$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^k$.

Answer (score 0):

For $i=0,1,2....$ put $\; C_{1,i}=1$.

Assume the following recurrence hypothesis

$$(A(x))^n=\sum_{i\in N}C_{n,i}x^i.$$

$$(A(x))^{n+1}
=(A(x))^n\sum_{j\in N}x^j$$

$$=\sum_{i,j \in N}C_{n,i}C_{1,j}x^{i+j}$$

$$=\sum_{i\in N}(\sum_{j=0}^i C_{n,j})x^i$$

thus, we get the following recursive formula

$$C_{n+1,N}=\sum_{j=0}^NC_{n,j}$$

with $C_{1,j}=1$ for $j=0,1,2...$.

For example, take $n=4,N=4$

$C_{2,0}=1,C_{2,1}=2,C_{2,2}=3,C_{2,3}=4,C_{2,4}=5$

$C_{3,0}=1,C_{3,1}=3,C_{3,2}=6,C_{3,3}=10,C_{3,4}=15$

$$C_{4,4}=1+3+6+10+15=35.$$

Comment: man, I don't understand the way you separate  C(n+1,i)Xi at third step

Comment: an example, A(x)^4 and I want to know the coefficient of x^4. When you use (N+1)^(n-1) equals 5^3 = 125, but the correct solution is 35 by using online calculator.

Comment: @AntonioGonzálezBorrego What about my formula. it gives $35$ for $n=4$ and $N=4$.